# Why is the setOnClickListener() has to be inside the onCreate()?

Tags: java, android

This code do not work if i place setOnClickListener outside of the onCreate method. I want to know why ? the logic is correct. But i get a red error in the place setOnClickListener outside onCreate()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  // has to be in inside onCreate()
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Button pausebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);  // has to be in inside onCreate()
        pausebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"pause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: can you add the code for outside onCreate() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the setonClickListener must be executed to work. Therefore if you put in another function not called, it won't work. You can also put it in onStart and onResume.

Another thing : you are not writting a program but creating a particular class object, an activity, which will be instantiated by android when your application start. Therefore, putting some code outside a method is an error.
I suggest you to look documentation about [activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/index.html) and [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: yah, i didnt put it in any method, thats the issue. technically i think you can place it in any method, but the code might not work, unless it is called. so putting it in oncreate make sense as it always gets executed first.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Called method are summed up in activity lifecycle (look the link in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

**onCreate():**

Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state, if there was one. Always followed by onStart().

Placing code outside of here it doesnt make sense, **WHY?**

Because your code will never be executed, in the activity startup only is executed the code that is in the onCreate and in the onResume.

Answer (score -1):

Because you have to create the button by reference and then set onclick listener to it.